# How to make Facebook’s Messenger desktop app start with Windows?

Tags: windows, facebook

The [offical desktop app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/messenger/9wzdncrf0083?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) works well on Windows, but apparently it doesn't show notification for new messages if the app is not started.

Is there an option to start it with Windows automatically? Such apps usually has a setting like that, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an option to start it with Windows automatically?

The option to automatically start this application does not exist.

There is an acceptable workaround to the limitation of Messenger.

1. Open File Explorer
2. Navigate to `shell:AppsFolder`
3. Select "Create Shortcut" on the Right-Click context menu for `Messenger`.  You will be a notification that the shortcut must be created on your desktop.
4. Navigate to `shell:startup` and place the shortcut within that directory
5. Reboot

Source: [How to launch Windows 10 apps on start up](https://mspoweruser.com/launch-windows-10-apps-start/)